# How to selectively concatenate lines ended with a new-line character inside a list using Python?

Tags: python, dna-sequence

I have a text file storing gene accession names and seuquences that reads like:
[original look of sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etce0.png)
and when I print it using Python, it shows that each line ended with a new line character:

```
['>hg19_knownGene_uc010nxr.1\n','cttgccgtcagccttttctttgacctcttctttctgttcatgtgtatttg\n','ctgtctcttagcccagacttcccgtgtcctttccaccgggcctttgagag\n','gtcacagggtcttgatgctgtggtcttcatctgcaggtgtctgacttcca\n','gcaactgctggcctgtgccagggtgcaagctgagcactggagtggagttt\n','>hg19_knownGene_uc001aai.1\n','aaggagatggtgctcttcttttttctttctgaattgtggccaccttcata\n','ccagtctgtcatggaacacttaagccgcttgagtgcctgctggtactccc\n','agccctgccatgcctgagccccctgcacacaaggagccaggagtaatcag\n','ggcagaccctttagggcacggggacttctggattgtgaaattggctctct\n','gggggccaaggccttctaacgttggtggaagtggctttggcttattgggt\n']
```

I don`t know how to concatenate lines of sequences into one single string which takes one line. And I need to maintain the gene accession name(header) and the first 101 nucleotides and have all these information stored in a new text file. So my desired output should be like:

```
>hg19_knownGene_uc010nxr.1
cttgccgtcagccttttctttgacctcttctttctgttcatgtgtatttgctgtctcttagcccagacttcccgtgtcctttccaccgggcctttgagagg
>hg19_knownGene_uc001aai.1
aaggagatggtgctcttcttttttctttctgaattgtggccaccttcataccagtctgtcatggaacacttaagccgcttgagtgcctgctggtactccca
```

I`m new to Python. Hope anyone can help me out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you read the text file in using a parser, it will handle this for you...
and give you a sequence object to work with.

http://scikit-bio.org/ or https://biopython.org/ are two libraries with sequence parsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is super simple. You can use the following:

```
output = lines[0]
output += "".join(line.strip() for line in lines[1:])
print(output)
```

Edit: Did not see that there's multiple headers per entry. To take care of that you can use

```
genes = []
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith(">"):
        genes.append(line)
    else:
        genes[-1] += line.strip()
for gene in genes:
    print(gene)
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do it

```
sequences = []
i = -1
for seq in list_of_seq:
    if seq[0]  == ">":
        sequences.append(seq[:-1] + "\n")
        i += 1            
    else:
        sequences[i] += seq[:-1]

for i in range(len(sequences)):
    with open(str(i)+".txt", "w") as wrfile:
        wrfile.write("".join(sequences[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach:

"l" is your original list

store in ordered dictionary:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
ord_dict = OrderedDict()
for itm in l:
    if itm.strip().startswith(">"):
        key=itm.strip()     #if it starts with a '>' then it is a key
        value=''
    else:
        value = itm.strip()  #otherwise a value
        if key in ord_dict:
            ord_dict[key] += value   #append value to previous list
        else:
            ord_dict[key] = value    #new key
```

to print first 101 chars:

for key in ord_dict:
    print(key)
    print(ord_dict[key][:101])

This prints:

```
>hg19_knownGene_uc010nxr.1
cttgccgtcagccttttctttgacctcttctttctgttcatgtgtatttgctgtctcttagcccagacttcccgtgtcctttccaccgggcctttgagagg
>hg19_knownGene_uc001aai.1
aaggagatggtgctcttcttttttctttctgaattgtggccaccttcataccagtctgtcatggaacacttaagccgcttgagtgcctgctggtactccca
```